# Redirect URL with it's store view code

Tags: magento2, category, url-rewrite

I have multi websites in one magento. Magento version is 2.3.2

I have multiple categories in magento. I am showing here for "es" store view code.

https://localhost/catalizadores (Without slash at the end) redirects to https://localhost/es/catalizadores/

but

https://localhost/catalizadores/ (With slash at the end) does not redirect and is the same page as (https://localhost/catalizadores/)

So now i have 2 Urls for the same category page

```
https://localhost/catalizadores/
https://localhost/es/catalizadores/
```

I want always this URL **https://localhost/es/catalizadores/** (Always with store view code)

How can i achieve this? Any idea? I have multiple category URLs so i am not preferring to add in .htaccess file.

Comment: have you enabled *Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories*, does that help?

Comment: It is enabled. But doesn't help

Comment: Why would the category url without store code be published anywhere if the canonical url is set with the store code? Google should index it correctly.

Comment: This issue concerning redirection that affect Google Analytics and AdWords. So i need solution for it.

Comment: The url wihout the store code will goto the default store view. Either you would need to redirect based on browser language (won't work for crawlers / google etc) or redirect to one default store view. Otherwise I don't think it is possible.

Comment: I think it is possible. Let's wait for some other people's answer.

Comment: Any thoughts on this?